# Creating a save as function in python

Tags: python, file, tkinter, save

I'm trying to create a function to save data taken from multiple Entry widgets in my code and create a new save file storing the data from all the entries.

I made a entry list called entries and try to pull from that but can't get it quite right. It will create the file but its always blank.

This is the code for my save as function using tkinter widgets.

```
def file_save_as(self):
    fout = asksaveasfile(mode = 'a', defaultextension = '.txt')
    with open('fout', 'a') as f:
        for entry in self.entries:
            f.write("%s\n" % entry)
```

Comment: Are you meaning to make `'fout'` a string in the line `with open('fout', 'a') as f:`, or should it be the `fout` variable?

Comment: `asksaveasfile` returns an already open file. To get the value from an entry widget, use the documented method `get()`.

Comment: Or use `asksaveasfilename` to get the filename only.

Comment: i was trying to assign the filename to a variable fout and then keep it open so i can write in the data, i realize i may need to change that, this is my first program in python so still learning

Comment: i can get the value from the entry widget using get() and then i placed it in a list, now im trying to write the data from the list to a new save file

Comment: The problem is that `'fout'` is _not_ your `fout` variable, it's just a string! As a first step, the line `with open('fout', 'a') as f:` needs to change to `with open(fout, 'a') as f:`.

Comment: @101 tried that and when i try to save a file it gives this

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tim and Steph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Tim and Steph/Desktop/Python apps/ECP_Calc/ECP_Calc GUI.py", line 37, in file_save_as
    with open(fout, 'a') as f:
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/Tim and Steph/Desktop/Python apps/ECP_Calc/ECPs/test2.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: Yep, because `asksaveasfile` returns an _opened file_. `open` expects a _filename_. So you're trying to open the file twice, hence the error. Change `asksaveasfile` to `asksaveasfilename`, as that returns a _filename_. Alternatively you could just manipulate the `fout` file instead of the `f` file.

Comment: got it thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def file_save_as(self):
    fout = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.txt')
    try:
        with open(fout, 'w') as output:
            for x in self.entries:
                output.write(x.get())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Cancelled save or error in filename")
```